# View previous user messages on Azure Bot

Tags: botframework, bots, azure-bot-service, direct-line-botframework

How do I show the previous user messages in Azure Bot service ?
I have them fetched from the database,I can print them on my console.
Lets say I have message U1 from user 1 and B1 the reply of bot to this message.How do I make the bot send U1?

Whenever I try to send U1 and B1 both go out as bot messages.
I am using Microsoft Azure Bot.

Edit 1 :  I tried the sendConversationHistory() method in Node.js and it works fine.I was able to view the messages on the bot emulator v4. But when the same code goes to deployment, it says bad activities. Can someone help me here?

[image]

Error message on deployment :

```
Error: Invalid activities
at new RestError (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\@azure\ms-rest-js\lib\restError.ts:18:5)
at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\@azure\ms-rest-js\lib\policies\deserializationPolicy.ts:117:27
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7),code: 'BadSyntax',statusCode: 400,
```

Activities being sent are of the form mentioned below in the code :

```
const newLocal = [{
    type: 'message', text: 'User message', from: context.activity.from, localTimezone: 'America/Los_Angeles', serviceUrl: context.activity.serviceUrl,
    channelId: context.activity.channelId, callerId: 'abc', recipient: context.activity.recipient, label: 'test', valueType: 'test', listenFor: ['nothing'],
    conversation: { isGroup: false, conversationType: 'test', tenantId: 'abc', id: context.activity.from.id, name: context.activity.from.name, message: 'User message' }
  },
  {
    type: 'message', text: 'Bot message!', from: context.activity.recipient, localTimezone: 'America/Los_Angeles', serviceUrl: context.activity.serviceUrl,
    channelId: context.activity.channelId, callerId: 'abc', recipient: context.activity.from, label: 'test', valueType: 'test', listenFor: ['nothing'],
    conversation: { isGroup: false, conversationType: 'test', tenantId: 'abc', id: context.activity.from.id, name: context.activity.from.name, message: 'Botmessage' }
  }
  ];
```

My question is if it works fine while testing on the emulator, why does it show bad activities while deploying?

Comment: Are you using Web Chat? And can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Yes.I am using Webchat. Currently every message stored in the database has 2 keys.User who sent the message,and the one who received it. Now when ever the bot initialises,I am first fetching the messages from the database at the backend and then sending out activities from the bot for each message obtained to the front end.
The problem is : since a bot is sending out an activity every message gets sent out as a bot message.So a user message sent as an activity goes as a message by the bot. I will continue in the next comment.

Comment: While sending out an activity from the bot,I am using the _from_ key to specifically mention that the user is the sender.But I think it gets overwritten, Because the actual sender is the bot. I am using `await context.sendActivities()` and passing an array of activities here.
I guess _sendActivities()_ overwrites the _from_ key in the message to the actual sender and not the one we provide it.Is there some another workaround?

Comment: Should I assume you're using the JavaScript SDK?

Comment: Yes.Node js at the backend, React for the frontend

Comment: Is there something similar for Node.js ? I am not thoroughly familiar with c#.I checked the documentation but that too has support only for c#.

Comment: You can see it in the Node SDK reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/id-id/javascript/api/botframework-connector/conversations?view=botbuilder-ts-latest#sendconversationhistory-string--transcript--requestoptionsbase-). But remember that there's parity between languages in Bot Builder v4, and they all use the same underlying Bot Framework schema/protocol. You can see it in the API reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference#send-conversation-history).

Comment: @KyleDelaney thanks for the help. I will try this out and let you know. Where are we specifying the original sender of an activity in sendConversationHistory()? How will the client understand that the previous message was from the bot or the user itself?

Comment: Also,should I totally drop the idea of sending activities using context.sendActivities()?

Comment: Activities have a `from` property which specifies the sender. And you should never use `context.sendActivities()` to simulate a message from the user to the bot.

Comment: What I did was: I wrote context.sendActivity() at the backend.(from the bot end).For user messages obtained from the database, I specified the from key in the activity to point to that user.But still while sending out from the backend, these get sent out as bot messages. So what do you suggest to go on about sending these activities(obtained from the database,which are a mix of user and bot messages) from the bot to the user?

Comment: I already answered that question. You need to use `sendConversationHistory()` to send a transcript that contains both user-to-bot messages and bot-to-user messages. You cannot have the bot send user-to-bot messages with `sendActivity()`. Are you willing to give `sendConversationHistory()` a try?

Comment: Oh okay.Got it.I will totally give it a try today and let you know.Thanks a lot for helping me out!I was following the wrong route all this way.I think I need to proceed in the other direction.Thanks mate!I will surely let you know about the update on this in a day or two.

Comment: Thanks for the help @KyleDelaney. The sendConversationHistory() seems to work great on bot emulator. I was a bit puzzled about what exactly is callerId.The docs say it is _A string containing an IRI identifying the caller of a bot. This field is not intended to be transmitted over  the wire, but is instead populated by bots and clients based on cryptographically verifiable data that asserts the identity of the callers (e.g. tokens)._ I did not understand much about this,do you seem to have an idea? Currently, I have hardcoded that value but I am not sure what would happen at deployment time.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you're talking about and you haven't linked to the doc you're quoting. You might want to ask a new question since that sounds like an unrelated issue, and this question is closed anyway.

Comment: I am really sorry.I think I will open up another question if required.Thanks a lot for your help! We are going to deploy it today and see whether it works on the server just like it worked on bot emulator v4.Thanks for your help! @KyleDelaney

Comment: @KyleDelaney can you please look at the post edit?

Comment: You said you were going to open another question. Have you done that?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Okay,I think i will do that. I thought I would put up here for continuation's sake.