# History messages

Tags: botframework, bots, azure-bot-service, direct-line-botframework

My previous question related to sending history messages was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62655061/view-previous-user-messages-on-azure-bot).

I tried the sendConversationHistory() method in Node.js and it works fine.I was able to view the messages on the bot emulator v4. But when the same code goes to deployment, it says bad activities. Can someone help me here?

Messages on emulator :
[image]

Error message on deployment :

```
Error: Invalid activities
at new RestError (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\@azure\ms-rest-js\lib\restError.ts:18:5)
at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\@azure\ms-rest-js\lib\policies\deserializationPolicy.ts:117:27
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7),code: 'BadSyntax',statusCode: 400,
```

Activities being sent are of the form mentioned below in the code :

```
const newLocal = [{
    type: 'message', text: 'User message', from: context.activity.from, localTimezone: 'America/Los_Angeles', serviceUrl: context.activity.serviceUrl,
    channelId: context.activity.channelId, callerId: 'abc', recipient: context.activity.recipient, label: 'test', valueType: 'test', listenFor: ['nothing'],
    conversation: { isGroup: false, conversationType: 'test', tenantId: 'abc', id: context.activity.from.id, name: context.activity.from.name, message: 'User message' }
  },
  {
    type: 'message', text: 'Bot message!', from: context.activity.recipient, localTimezone: 'America/Los_Angeles', serviceUrl: context.activity.serviceUrl,
    channelId: context.activity.channelId, callerId: 'abc', recipient: context.activity.from, label: 'test', valueType: 'test', listenFor: ['nothing'],
    conversation: { isGroup: false, conversationType: 'test', tenantId: 'abc', id: context.activity.from.id, name: context.activity.from.name, message: 'Botmessage' }
  }
  ];
```

My question is if it works fine while testing on the emulator, why does it show *bad activities* while deploying?

EDIT 1 :
I apologise for not specifying the details.We have 2 repos, the front-end repo deployed currently on our company website and the backend logic in another repo.The bot's front-end is in a different repo and the backend is a separate repo.The front-end repo talks to the backend via directline.

So whatever changes one makes to the front-end repo or the backend repo, they are committed and then Azure pipelines are used to build and run them .So, I make changes to the backend code, use sendConvHistory method at the backend and then run the pipeline.Before running on the Azure pipeline, I test out the backend code on emulator.So, while running on the Azure pipeline the error message pops up.The results of testing out on emulator is in the pic above.

The Azure pipeline is basically the deployed code.First the code gets built there, then it is deployed and we can test out accordingly.Let's say I made changes to the back end in this case, and then I run the pipeline, the code gets deployed and I can test it out.I am sorry for making it too long, but I thought this would clear up things.

Comment: There is no Emulator-deployment dichotomy. "Emulator" is a channel while "deployed" is a hosting location. You can use the Emulator to talk to a deployed bot, and you can use other channels to talk to a local bot. So you need to give us some more information and try a few things. Are we to assume you're using Web Chat to talk to a deployed bot? Have you tried connecting Emulator to the deployed bot? Have you tried connecting Web Chat to a local bot using ngrok? Have you tried removing all extraneous properties from the activities you're testing with?

Comment: I have updated the post!

Comment: When someone flags your question as a duplicate, that means you should read the answer to the question that your question was a duplicate of. If you read Eric's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54641519/2122672), you should see that you need to provide unique activity ID's in your transcript. I also notice that you're passing user ID's as your conversation ID's. Why not clean up your sample activities like I asked? You don't need all those properties,so try it with just type, text, id, timestamp, from, and recipient.

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I send chat transcript? SendConversationHistoryAsync() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53181825/how-do-i-send-chat-transcript-sendconversationhistoryasync-not-working)